# How to align tab to center in android?

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

Thats my tab.
[image: my tab]

I want to align it to center of the screen. (horizontal and vertical)

The table is created dynamically from java.

I tried set

```
TableLayout t1 = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.maintable);
t1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

But it align it only from top.

```
public class TabActivity extends Activity {

Trny t = Trny.getInstance();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab);

    TableLayout t1 = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.maintable);
    t1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        // first row of table   

        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);

        TextView place = new TextView(this);
        poradi.setText("P"  );
        poradi.setPadding(10, 5, 10, 5);
        tr.addView(place);

        TextView nameOfTeam = new TextView(this);
        nazTymu.setText("Nazev"  );
        nazTymu.setPadding(10, 5, 10, 5);
        tr.addView(nameOfTeam);

        TextView matchesPlayed = new TextView(this);
        odehraneZapasy.setText("Z" );
        odehraneZapasy.setPadding(10, 5, 10, 5);
        tr.addView(matchesPlayed);

        TextView numbefOfWins = new TextView(this);
        pocetVyher.setText("V" );
        pocetVyher.setPadding(10, 5, 10, 5);
        tr.addView(numbefOfWins);

        TextView numberOfTies = new TextView(this);
        pocetRemiz.setText("R" );
        pocetRemiz.setPadding(10, 5, 10, 5);
        tr.addView(numberOfTies);

        TextView numberOfLoses = new TextView(this);
        pocetProher.setText("P" );
        pocetProher.setPadding(10, 5, 10, 5);
        tr.addView(numberOfLoses);

        TextView goalsScored = new TextView(this);
        skorePlus.setText("VG" );
        skorePlus.setPadding(10, 5, 10, 5);
        tr.addView(goalsScored);

        TextView goalsGained = new TextView(this);
        skoreMinus.setText("OG" );
        skoreMinus.setPadding(10, 5, 10, 5);
        tr.addView(goalsGained);

        TextView numberOfPoints = new TextView(this);
        pocBodu.setText("B" );
        pocBodu.setPadding(10, 5, 10, 5);
        tr.addView(numberOfPoints);


        t1.addView(tr);

                 //more rows dynamically created from java

}

 }
```

XML file

```
            <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"   
            android:id="@+id/maintable" >
            </TableLayout>
```

How can i achieve this? Thanks guys.

Comment: That should have fixed it. try setting CENTER_HORIZONTAL and CENTER_VERTICAL. You should give it in the layout file itself as you dont need to be shifted dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

change your layout XML to this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TableLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
        android:id="@+id/maintable"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" >
        </TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```